# how to create a stored procedure in mysql the right way

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

PHP mysqli quickguide for stored procedures, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php :

```
if (!$mysqli->query("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS p") ||
    !$mysqli->query("CREATE PROCEDURE p(IN id_val INT) BEGIN INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES(id_val); END;")) {
    echo "Stored procedure creation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

does this not delete the procedure then replace it? is this the correct way to do it? what is the point in deleting it? does deleting it not negate the whole point of having a procedure which you can call for the duration of a MySQL connection?

Comment: AFAIK dropping the procedure if it exists and recreating it from scratch is how it works in all SQL database systems.

Comment: do you know why it has to be dropped? is it just good practice? if so why?

Comment: I would imagine that it's just simpler to do it that way, rather than having some elaborate editing mechanism.  Normally, you don't create your stored procedures every time you establish a MySQL connection; you put your stored procedures in there once, and leave them there unless they change.

Comment: in Oracle the syntax includes CREATE OR REPLACE - so not technically a drop and recreate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to drop the 'old' procedure first, otherwise the CREATE will fail with an "already exists" errors. It's the same for pretty much EVERY object in a database, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE foo ...   // creates the table
CREATE TABLE foo ...   // will **NOT** replace the one just created
```

you cannot 'overwrite' a table/proc/db just by redefining it. you have to drop the original one first.

Consider the chaos that'd occur if some poor DBA at a major bank accidentally ran

```
CREATE DATABASE clients;
```

and trashed their entire client db because the DB engine replaced the original DB with this new empty one.

Comment: so if the stored procedures for every connection are remembered separately for every different connection, and I know I never have two procedures of the same name, I could test if the procedure exists and only create it if it doesn't exist? negating the need for me to drop the procedure if it does exist?

Comment: similar to CREATE OR REPLACE in Oracle?

Comment: no idea about oracle specifically, but generally sprocs are stored permanently and available for any/all connections/users.

Comment: available for any/all connections/users but just for that database?